# SQL Server - Remove results B from results A, insert to original table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, ssms

## Table structure

- RowId - uniqueidentifier, default: newid()
- **ModuleName - nchar 25**
- **Type - int**
- **Id - int**
- **ParentId - int**
- LanguageId - int
- Text - nvarchar 1024
- X - int
- Y - int
- Width - int
- Height - int
- Pending - smallint, default: 0
- Remarks - nvarchar 250

## What I need?

- Take all the records where `LanguageId = 1051`, let's call this set **A**
- Take all the records where `LanguageId != 1051`, let's call this set **B**
- Remove from set **B** where *all* these conditions apply:

  - `B.ModuleName = A.ModuleName`
  - `B.Type = A.Type`
  - `B.Id = A.Id`
  - `B.ParentId = A.ParentId`
- Remove duplicates in set **B** based on `ModuleName`, `Type`, `Id` and `ParentId` (if all are the same, leave only one of the records)
- In set **B**, change all `LanguageId = 1051`
- Insert set **B** to the original `Translation` table

[SQLFiddle.com](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e76cd)

I can imagine the process, but I have no idea how to achieve this in SQL.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: A lot of talk. Set http://www.sqlfiddle.com so someone can help. Provide sample input => desired output.

Comment: I got rid of the unnecessary talk, only leaving the structure and what query I need to build. Unfortunately, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, but [sqlfiddle.com](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0be4/2) yields no results to `SELECT`, even after several `INSERT`s.

Comment: Do you know [this image](https://sqlwithmanoj.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/sql_joins.jpg) of SQL Joins? I've only tried these. But it seems `JOIN` is not the way to go. Or it's just me who is getting lost in it.

Comment: You have to put inserts on the schema side of sqlfiddle. also you could provide a small sample data as lad say, sample input => desired output.

Comment: and what is desire output? Specially a sample of this rule `Remove from set B where all these conditions apply:`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: It should take all the records with `LanguageId <> 1051` from table `Translation`, apply the rules above (filter out any records that already has a counterpart with `LangaugeId = 1051`), and insert them as new records with `LanguageId = 1051`.

Comment: Please just take a picture and show us the result. Your words can be misinterpreted. Right now you dont get result because your conditions not return values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove from set B where all these conditions apply:

- B.ModuleName = A.ModuleName
- B.Type = A.Type
- B.Id = A.Id
- B.ParentId = A.ParentId

. Is Equal to this

```
SELECT *
FROM Translation B
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                   FROM Translation A
                   WHERE
                        A.LanguageId = 1051 
                    and B.ModuleName = A.ModuleName
                    and B.Type = A.Type
                    and B.Id = A.Id
                    and B.ParentId = A.ParentId
                )
and B.LanguageId <> 1051
```

- In set B, change all LanguageId = 1051

  ```
    SELECT B.*, 1051 as LenguajeID
    FROM Translation B
    <.. same as before ...>
  ```
- Insert set B to the original Translation table

  ```
    INSERT INTO Translation 
        SELECT [RowId],
          [ModuleName],
          [Type],
          [Id],
          [ParentId],
          1051 [LanguageId],
          [Text],
          [X],
          [Y],
          [Width],
          [Height],
          [Pending],
          [Remarks]
        FROM Translation B
        WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                           FROM Translation A
                           WHERE A.LanguageId = 1051 
                           and B.Type = A.Type
                           and B.Id = A.Id
                           and B.ParentId = A.ParentId
                           and B.ModuleName = A.ModuleName
                        )
        AND B.LanguageId <> 1051
  ```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e76cd/14) Only for the select

Comment: This is going the right direction, I'm already trying it. Will let you know what happens.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely it. One more thing I've noticed and added to the original post: "Remove duplicates in set **B** based on `ModuleName`, `Type`, `Id` and `ParentId` (if all are the same, leave only one of the records)". As there can be none to virtually unlimited records for each combination of these four columns, but I only need one. Still, I'm accepting this as it solves the original question. Thank you very much!

Comment: As I say show us the desire result, that save a lot of time. Please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Right now I dont see duplicate data in my result. Maybe you need a bigger sample data set? But probably just a `DISTINCT` on the select will be enough

Comment: Your last query is the desired result. I don't know how else to describe it, if not the guidelines of what should happen. I don't know what else to provide, when I didn't have any results till now. Dumbed down: The table contains three rows, with unique `RowId`, different `LanguageId`, identical `ParentId`. If, for that `ParentId` there's no record with `LanguageId = 1051`, create it, by copying one of the existing rows and changing the `LanguageId`, that's the basic idea, except there's approx. 150 000 rows, not three. And various combinations of the four emphasized columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into transision

select 1051 as LanguageId ,your columns.......

from B

left join  A
on B.ModuleName != A.ModuleName and
B.Type != A.Type  and
B.Id != A.Id  and
B.ParentId != A.ParentId
where B.LanguageId !=1051
```

Comment: While this may solve the OP's problem, a few words of explanation will help the current and future readers to understand your answer even better.